# "commonCapabilities:" block for Browserstack doesn't work

Tags: browserstack

Please help me with Browserstack. I'm setting up testing in WDIO(TS, Mocha) I want to add a "buildname" to Browserstack test suit. For that I put

```
commonCapabilities: {
        'bstack:options': {
            buildName: 'V0-build',
        }
    },
```

after

```
capabilities: [
        {
            browserName: 'Chrome',
            browserVersion: 'latest',
            'bstack:options': {
                os: 'Windows',
                osVersion: '11'
            }
        },
        {
            browserName: 'Safari',
            browserVersion: '14.1',
            'bstack:options': {
                os: 'OS X',
                osVersion: 'Big Sur'
            }
        }
```

but I don't get the build name in the left column on Browserstack dashboard.

I tried to reload VScode window, delete and install node_modules anew. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should pass the capability as below:

capabilities: [{
project: "First Webdriverio Android Project",
build: 'Webdriverio Android',
name: 'first_test',
device: 'Google Pixel 3',
os_version: "9.0",
app: process.env.BROWSERSTACK_APP_ID || 'bs://',
'browserstack.debug': true
}],

the same is mentioned on their link: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/getting-started/nodejs/webdriverio

Comment: Thank you for answer) Yes, its a simple way, but I don't want to copy one code ( buildName: 'V0-build',) for each browser entity.